# Inline images other than small ones not appearing on Outlook Web Client

Tags: java, image, exchangewebservices, webmail, ewsjavaapi

I need to send Inline images in the body of my automatic reply mail , but I noticed that any image larger than 15Kb is failing to render in the Outlook Webclient. The images are url encoded in base64 and the body of the mail is sent as a HTML file.

```
        EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.bind(service, mail.getItemId());
        email.setIsRead(true);
        email.update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
        EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
        EmailAddress from = new EmailAddress(supportId);
        message.setSubject("Re: "+mail.getSubject());
        MessageBody hmtlBody = composeHtmlBody(BOX_NAME+"("+mail.getCategory()+")");
        message.setBody(hmtlBody);
        message.getToRecipients().add(mail.getFrom());
        message.setFrom(from);
        message.sendAndSaveCopy();
```

this is my html code

```
<p>Estimado SeÃ±or/SeÃ±ora/SeÃ±orita,
    <br>
    <br>Reciba un cordial saludo, por favor su gentil ayuda comunicÃ¡ndose a nuestro Call Center 02-2999-999 o al 1700 800800 opciÃ³n 2 para que el asesor realice la respectiva verificaciÃ³n y le brinden el soporte adecuado.
    <br>
    <br>
    <img alt="Logo" src="BASE64URL" height="350" width="450">
    <br>Saludos cordiales.
    <br>
    <br>Asesor Virtual
```

Tried with cid and baseurl64 , none of these help in rendering the image [image_no_render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OldoN.png)